# Datatype not converting as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

i have columns with float dataype in oracle. Data will be look like this
1546.6,
0.0,
0.0

I tried with decimal datatype to get the similar data , but im getting integer datatype value without decimal points . how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are doing and what you are seeing.  Could you possibly update your question with a reproducible test case?

Comment: How did you define the column? `DECIMAL` is an integer. `DECIMAL(10)` is an integer. `DECIMAL(10,2)` is not. This is because the scale (the optional second number in the declaration) defaults to zero. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/A39YITOQ

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is just a *displaying* problem.

If you created a column whose datatype is a pure `NUMBER`, it allows various numeric values, including the ones with one decimal number.

```
SQL> create table test (col number);

Table created.
```

Values you'll store into the table:

```
SQL> insert into test (col)
  2    select 1546.6 from dual union all
  3    select    0.0 from dual;

2 rows created.
```

This is the default:

```
SQL> select * from test;

       COL
----------
    1546,6
         0
```

Presentation might differ; choose any format model you find appropriate, e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(col, '999g999g990d00') formatted_col
  2  from test;

FORMATTED_COL
---------------
       1.546,60
           0,00

SQL>
```

Comment: [Notes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF): The `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` data types can specify only fixed-point numbers. For those data types, the scale (`s`) **defaults to 0**.